# PnP Modern Search - search only a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-experience, sharepoint-search, pnp

I recently installed PnP Modern Search 4.0 for a SharePoint Teams site.

Out of the box, it seems like it's searching every file in every SharePoint site in my organization. I want it to only search a single list in my SharePoint site.

I have consulted documentation from various sources and YouTube videos for hours, but I'm not getting very far with it.

Comment: You can either provide KQL query text or result source ID to limit the search results. Check [this documentation](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-results/data-sources/).

Comment: I've read through that documentation. Can I get some help with my particular situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use following query in the Query template.

```
{searchTerms} path: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Echo/Lists/emilytest
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Where can I find more information about what I can put in this Query template box?

Answer (score 0):

PnP Modern Search is like a visualizer that allows you to display the items returned by SharePoint Search or Microsoft Search.
In other words, if you want to know how the Search works, you can refer to the Microsoft Learn documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference